# I can no longer boot into MacOS and it seems like I corrupted my partitions

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I'm not sure what I did, but I think I messed up my partitions on my 2TB FusionDrive on a n Intel Based Macbook Pro 2020. I believe I was on Monterey. I think the underlying cause is that I incorrectly deleted the bootcamp partition.

**Symptoms**:

- I get the flashing drive with a question mark error when I try to boot up
- I can only boot into internet recovery
- I cannnot boot into my mac
- I cannot boot into bootcamp

My main objective is getting ahold of files/folders that sat on my desktop. And files and folders that sat in my personal/user folder.

---

I'm using my daughter's Mac and Target Disk Mode to access the drive/partitions for all the details below.

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1.8 TB     disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk3

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk20

/dev/disk21 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk21

/dev/disk22 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk22

/dev/disk23 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk23

/dev/disk24 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk24

/dev/disk25 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +10.5 MB    disk25

/dev/disk26 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 GB     disk26

-bash-3.2#
```

And below is the response to the following command

```
diskutil unmount disk0s2
sudo dd if=/dev/disk0s2 bs=512 count=3 | hexdump -Cv
```

```
hark@sophies-mbp ~ % diskutil unmount disk2s2
disk2s2 was already unmounted
hark@sophies-mbp ~ % sudo dd if=/dev/disk2s2 bs=512 count=3 | hexdump -Cv
Password:
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.016207 secs (94774 bytes/sec)
00000000  5c d4 7e 37 d9 13 a9 53  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |\.~7...S........|
00000010  4f bd 5e 01 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |O.^.............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  47 8c 1d 1d 00 00 00 00  |NXSB....G.......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b4 5e 79 00 1d 65 41 1c  |.........^y..eA.|
00000050  86 62 00 ef b9 cb 17 74  30 af e4 00 00 00 00 00  |.b.....t0.......|
00000060  50 bd 5e 01 00 00 00 00  18 01 00 00 ac 6c 00 00  |P.^..........l..|
00000070  c1 b2 05 00 00 00 00 00  15 46 05 00 00 00 00 00  |.........F......|
00000080  02 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  2e af e4 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  a5 61 20 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.a .............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  2d 61 0d 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...-a......|
000000c0  06 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  0a 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  22 15 10 00 00 00 00 00  |........".......|
000000e0  2f 61 0d 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |/a..............|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000130  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000190  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000220  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000270  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000280  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000290  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000300  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000310  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000320  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000330  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000340  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000350  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000360  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000380  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e4 eb 20 3f 00 00 00 00  |.......... ?....|
000003e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000400  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000410  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000420  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000440  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000460  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000470  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000480  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000490  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  91 fb 4a 04 00 00 00 00  |..........J.....|
00000500  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000510  b0 65 3a 04 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.e:.............|
00000520  01 00 04 00 08 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000530  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000540  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000550  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000560  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 be 04 c9 2c 9c 07 00  |............,...|
00000570  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000580  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000590  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000600
```

and below is the output for

```
diskutil info disk2s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
```

```
hark@sophies-mbp ~ % diskutil info disk2s2 | grep -e Size -e Offset
   Partition Offset:          314597376 Bytes (76806 4096-Byte-Device-Blocks)
   Disk Size:                 1.8 TB (1806000168960 Bytes) (exactly 3527344080 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes
```

Here's what DiskUtility looks like from my daughter's laptop
[image]
[image]

And here's what it looks like from the affected laptop.
[image]

This is what I get for the command `gpt -r show disk1`.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Seems time to restore from backup? It’s hard to recover from corrupted partition tables

Comment: I see you are showing 1,806,000,168,960 bytes and probably should be showing 2,000,796,545,024 bytes. Can you post the output from `gpt -r show disk1`?

Comment: @DavidAnderson 
On Target Disk mode, I get a

gpt show: unable to open device 'disk2': Permission denied

response. 

Let me try recovery, but will take some time to boot.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your last comment. What command did you enter? I asked for `gpt -r show disk1`. I can not image why you received a message regarding `disk2`. I suppose I should have asked for  `sudo gpt -r show disk1`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I just added the screenshot to the original post (with a result).

I was in target disk mode in my original reply and using the other laptop (not the affected one). On the second Mac, the relevant disk was listed as disk2. I suppose I'll just stick to doing things in Recovery on the affected Mac.

Comment: Look at the numbers you posted: (440918010 sectors+47557709 sectors)*4096 bytes/sector=2,000,796,545,024 bytes. This is the number posted in my first [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/653755).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the second partition of `disk1` to match the size of the APFS container. The commands are given below.

```
gpt -f remove -i 2 disk1
gpt -f add -i 2 -b 76806 -s 488475719 -t apfs disk1
```

This change does not guarantee that there is nothing else wrong.

Comment: This worked. Incredible. Thank you so much.